# HTTP working, SSH and FTP refusing connection

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ftp

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on an old P4 machine. I have installed AMPPS, so that it can serve a dev server on local network.

After configuring everything (router config, etc.), I can access web server without any issues on port 80 but FTP on port 21 and SSH on port 22 are refusing connections from other PCs within the network.

When accessing FTP from the same machine, it works, which tells me that Pure-FTPd is working fine.

What could be the cause of this weird issue?

**EDIT**

UFW Status:

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 21                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 21 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 4] 80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:fsp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:http

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Pure FTP Config:

```
############################################################
#                                                          #
#         Configuration file for pure-ftpd wrappers        #
#                                                          #
############################################################

# If you want to run Pure-FTPd with this configuration   
# instead of command-line options, please run the
# following command :
#
# {$path}/Pure-FTPd//sbin/pure-config.pl {$path}/Pure-FTPd//etc/pure-ftpd.conf
#
# Please don't forget to have a look at documentation at
# http://www.pureftpd.org/documentation.shtml for a complete list of
# options.

# Cage in every user in his home directorysdfsdfj sdfksdfgksgf

ChrootEveryone              yes



# If the previous option is set to "no", members of the following group
# won't be caged. Others will be. If you don't want chroot()ing anyone,
# just comment out ChrootEveryone and TrustedGID.

# TrustedGID                    100



# Turn on compatibility hacks for broken clients

BrokenClientsCompatibility  no



# Maximum number of simultaneous users

MaxClientsNumber            50



# Fork in background

Daemonize                   yes



# Maximum number of sim clients with the same IP address

MaxClientsPerIP             8



# If you want to log all client commands, set this to "yes".
# This directive can be duplicated to also log server responses.

VerboseLog                  yes



# List dot-files even when the client doesn't send "-a".

DisplayDotFiles             yes



# Don't allow authenticated users - have a public anonymous FTP only.

AnonymousOnly               no



# Disallow anonymous connections. Only allow authenticated users.

NoAnonymous                 no



# Syslog facility (auth, authpriv, daemon, ftp, security, user, local*)
# The default facility is "ftp". "none" disables logging.

SyslogFacility              ftp



# Display fortune cookies

# FortunesFile              /usr/share/fortune/zippy



# Don't resolve host names in log files. Logs are less verbose, but 
# it uses less bandwidth. Set this to "yes" on very busy servers or
# if you don't have a working DNS.

DontResolve                 yes



# Maximum idle time in minutes (default = 15 minutes)

MaxIdleTime                 15



# LDAP configuration file (see README.LDAP)

# LDAPConfigFile                /etc/pureftpd-ldap.conf



# MySQL configuration file (see README.MySQL)

# MySQLConfigFile               /etc/pureftpd-mysql.conf


# Postgres configuration file (see README.PGSQL)

# PGSQLConfigFile               /etc/pureftpd-pgsql.conf


# PureDB user database (see README.Virtual-Users)

PureDB                        {$path}/Pure-FTPd/etc/pureftpd.pdb


# Path to pure-authd socket (see README.Authentication-Modules)

# ExtAuth                       /var/run/ftpd.sock



# If you want to enable PAM authentication, uncomment the following line

# PAMAuthentication             yes



# If you want simple Unix (/etc/passwd) authentication, uncomment this

UnixAuthentication            yes



# Please note that LDAPConfigFile, MySQLConfigFile, PAMAuthentication and
# UnixAuthentication can be used only once, but they can be combined
# together. For instance, if you use MySQLConfigFile, then UnixAuthentication,
# the SQL server will be asked. If the SQL authentication fails because the
# user wasn't found, another try # will be done with /etc/passwd and
# /etc/shadow. If the SQL authentication fails because the password was wrong,
# the authentication chain stops here. Authentication methods are chained in
# the order they are given. 



# 'ls' recursion limits. The first argument is the maximum number of
# files to be displayed. The second one is the max subdirectories depth

LimitRecursion              10000 8



# Are anonymous users allowed to create new directories ?

AnonymousCanCreateDirs      no



# If the system is more loaded than the following value,
# anonymous users aren't allowed to download.

MaxLoad                     4



# Port range for passive connections replies. - for firewalling.

# PassivePortRange          30000 50000



# Force an IP address in PASV/EPSV/SPSV replies. - for NAT.
# Symbolic host names are also accepted for gateways with dynamic IP
# addresses.

# ForcePassiveIP                192.168.0.1



# Upload/download ratio for anonymous users.

# AnonymousRatio                1 10



# Upload/download ratio for all users.
# This directive superscedes the previous one.

# UserRatio                 1 10



# Disallow downloading of files owned by "ftp", ie.
# files that were uploaded but not validated by a local admin.

AntiWarez                   yes



# IP address/port to listen to (default=all IP and port 21).

Bind                      127.0.0.1,21



# Maximum bandwidth for anonymous users in KB/s

# AnonymousBandwidth            8



# Maximum bandwidth for *all* users (including anonymous) in KB/s
# Use AnonymousBandwidth *or* UserBandwidth, both makes no sense.

# UserBandwidth             8



# File creation mask. <umask for files>:<umask for dirs> .
# 177:077 if you feel paranoid.

Umask                       133:022



# Minimum UID for an authenticated user to log in.

MinUID                      100



# Allow FXP transfers for authenticated users.

AllowUserFXP                no



# Allow anonymous FXP for anonymous and non-anonymous users.

AllowAnonymousFXP           no



# Users can't delete/write files beginning with a dot ('.')
# even if they own them. If TrustedGID is enabled, this group
# will have access to dot-files, though.

ProhibitDotFilesWrite       no



# Prohibit *reading* of files beginning with a dot (.history, .ssh...)

ProhibitDotFilesRead        no



# Never overwrite files. When a file whose name already exist is uploaded,
# it get automatically renamed to file.1, file.2, file.3, ...

AutoRename                  no



# Disallow anonymous users to upload new files (no = upload is allowed)

AnonymousCantUpload         no



# Only connections to this specific IP address are allowed to be
# non-anonymous. You can use this directive to open several public IPs for
# anonymous FTP, and keep a private firewalled IP for remote administration.
# You can also only allow a non-routable local IP (like 10.x.x.x) to
# authenticate, and keep a public anon-only FTP server on another IP.

TrustedIP                  127.0.0.1



# If you want to add the PID to every logged line, uncomment the following
# line.

LogPID                     yes



# Create an additional log file with transfers logged in a Apache-like format :
# fw.c9x.org - jedi [13/Dec/1975:19:36:39] "GET /ftp/linux.tar.bz2" 200 21809338
# This log file can then be processed by www traffic analyzers.

AltLog                     clf:{$path}/Pure-FTPd/logs/pure-ftpd.log



# Create an additional log file with transfers logged in a format optimized
# for statistic reports.

# AltLog                     stats:/var/log/pureftpd.log



# Create an additional log file with transfers logged in the standard W3C
# format (compatible with most commercial log analyzers)

# AltLog                     w3c:/var/log/pureftpd.log



# Disallow the CHMOD command. Users can't change perms of their files.

#NoChmod                     yes



# Allow users to resume and upload files, but *NOT* to delete them.

#KeepAllFiles                yes



# Automatically create home directories if they are missing

#CreateHomeDir               yes



# Enable virtual quotas. The first number is the max number of files.
# The second number is the max size of megabytes.
# So 1000:10 limits every user to 1000 files and 10 Mb.

#Quota                       1000:10



# If your pure-ftpd has been compiled with standalone support, you can change
# the location of the pid file. The default is /var/run/pure-ftpd.pid

PIDFile                     {$path}/Pure-FTPd/logs/pure-ftpd.pid



# If your pure-ftpd has been compiled with pure-uploadscript support,
# this will make pure-ftpd write info about new uploads to
# /var/run/pure-ftpd.upload.pipe so pure-uploadscript can read it and
# spawn a script to handle the upload.
# Don't enable this option if you don't actually use pure-uploadscript.

#CallUploadScript yes



# This option is useful with servers where anonymous upload is 
# allowed. As /var/ftp is in /var, it save some space and protect 
# the log files. When the partition is more that X percent full,
# new uploads are disallowed.

MaxDiskUsage               99



# Set to 'yes' if you don't want your users to rename files.

#NoRename                  yes



# Be 'customer proof' : workaround against common customer mistakes like
# 'chmod 0 public_html', that are valid, but that could cause ignorant
# customers to lock their files, and then keep your technical support busy
# with silly issues. If you're sure all your users have some basic Unix
# knowledge, this feature is useless. If you're a hosting service, enable it.

CustomerProof              yes



# Per-user concurrency limits. It will only work if the FTP server has
# been compiled with --with-peruserlimits (and this is the case on
# most binary distributions) .
# The format is : <max sessions per user>:<max anonymous sessions>
# For instance, 3:20 means that the same authenticated user can have 3 active
# sessions max. And there are 20 anonymous sessions max.

# PerUserLimits            3:20



# When a file is uploaded and there is already a previous version of the file
# with the same name, the old file will neither get removed nor truncated.
# Upload will take place in a temporary file and once the upload is complete,
# the switch to the new version will be atomic. For instance, when a large PHP
# script is being uploaded, the web server will still serve the old version and
# immediatly switch to the new one as soon as the full file will have been
# transfered. This option is incompatible with virtual quotas.

# NoTruncate               yes



# This option can accept three values :
# 0 : disable SSL/TLS encryption layer (default).
# 1 : accept both traditional and encrypted sessions.
# 2 : refuse connections that don't use SSL/TLS security mechanisms,
#     including anonymous sessions.
# Do _not_ uncomment this blindly. Be sure that :
# 1) Your server has been compiled with SSL/TLS support (--with-tls),
# 2) A valid certificate is in place,
# 3) Only compatible clients will log in.

# TLS                      1


# List of ciphers that will be accepted for SSL/TLS connections
# Prefix with -S: in order to totally disable SSL but not TLS.

# TLSCipherSuite           HIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:!SSLv2:+SSLv3



# Listen only to IPv4 addresses in standalone mode (ie. disable IPv6)
# By default, both IPv4 and IPv6 are enabled.

# IPV4Only                 yes



# Listen only to IPv6 addresses in standalone mode (ie. disable IPv4)
# By default, both IPv4 and IPv6 are enabled.

# IPV6Only                 yes

# UTF-8 support for file names (RFC 2640)
# Define charset of the server filesystem and optionnally the default charset
# for remote clients if they don't use UTF-8.
# Works only if pure-ftpd has been compiled with --with-rfc2640

# FileSystemCharset big5
# ClientCharset     big5
```

`netstat -nptl` Output

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:21            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17153/pure-ftpd (SE
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      929/dnsmasq     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25138/sshd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6288/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60800         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13714/Ampps     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      25138/sshd      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      6288/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2040/httpd      
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      2066/mysqld     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2040/httpd
```

Comment: Check your firewall on the server. Then, Check your firewall on the router,  for allowed ports.

Comment: @j0h Sorry, I forgot to mention, I've checked firewall on router and server, they seem to have configured properly.

Comment: Ok first troubleshoot ssh: Can you share the config you have done in sshd_config? What errors do you get when you ssh? Are you using windows machine or another linux box to ssh?

Comment: Even if they seem ok, try disabling firewall on server and then connect. Are you sure, you've configured ftp and ssh to work on appropriate interface? If ftp can connect locally, that means you might be connecting to 127.0.0.1, not using external interface (so it's either blocked on server or router, or is not configured to listen). To clarify, you can show output of `sudo ufw status numbered`or `sudo iptables -L`(remember to edit out any private info)

Comment: @MarekBettman I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Your PureFTP is only listening on localhost, `127.0.0.1`.  A lot of FTP clients have that as a default setup for some reason.

If it were listening to the Internet, it'd be showing `0.0.0.0:21` on that list of output from netstat.

From what I found online, you have to find whatever starts up PureFTPd and pass it the `--bind` argument.  Specifically, `--bind 0.0.0.0,21` if you want it to listen on the Internet.  This may be in the service file for how it's started, i.e. in `/etc/init.d/pureftpfd` perhaps.

Comment: Thomas is right, you need to listen on the public IP or to 0.0.0.0.  It's only listening on localhost, so you'll only be able to access it from localhost.  There are no firewall issues in play

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for ssh, `sudo ufw allow 22` or `sudo ufw allow ssh`should help.

I see, that port 21 is unblocked for FTP already, so I guess you have some PureFTP misconfiguration, can you post config file? (alternatively you can try `sudo ufw allow ftp` - maybe it will rewrite some rules - I generally hate reading output of iptables -L on ufw enabled systems).

Comment: I added rule for ssh like you said but the connection is still getting refused. Did the same for ftp, the result is same. As for Pure-FTP config, I have updated my question.

Comment: There is your problem:
# IP address/port to listen to (default=all IP and port 21).
Bind                      127.0.0.1,21
change it to your external IP (and restart pureftd after)

Comment: just a thought - did you actually started pureftp and ssh services ? can you post output of `netstat -nptl`?

Comment: and just to be completely sure it's not firewall run `sudo ufw disable` and try to connect then; `sudo ufw enable` to restore firewall

Comment: also, post your /etc/ssh/sshd_config :)

Comment: After restarting UFW, SSH seems to be working but FTP remains same. Output of netstat -npt1 is available in my question now. :) I changed IP in pure-ftp config to the public IP i.e. 192.168.1.6 but the result is same.

Comment: does netstat show `192.168.1.6:21` instead `127.0.0.1:21`? Did you restarted pureftp?

Comment: Yes, I did and no it never showed 192.168.1.6:21 and is still showing 127.0.0.1:21. :(

Comment: hmmm ... that is weird, just try to hash out that line - default will be to bind to all interfaces. Maybe try to reboot the machine.